# React - Button onClick not firing

Tags: reactjs

My button onClick is not firing the alert message:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Container, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarToggler, NavItem, NavLink } from 
'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './NavMenu.css';

export class Header extends Component {
static displayName = Header.name;
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sideMenuClick = this.sideMenuClick.bind(this);
}

sideMenuClick() {
    alert("hhhhhh");
    this.props.handleClick();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="headercon">
            <button onClick={this.sideMenuClick} className={"fas fa-sliders-h"} style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize: 16, width: 25, height: 25, float: 'right', marginRight: 20, }}></button>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Well. did you try to find out why? any error reported on the console? Looks fine to me and the sideMenuClick should be invoked as expected.

Comment: Everything looks fine. Did you pass the handleClick prop correctly? Here is a working codesandbox that might help https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-5ozmn?file=/index.js.

Comment: there are no console errors, not sure, i have passed the handleClick property correctly

Comment: adding  <button onClick={ () => alert("cccc") } className={"fas fa-sliders-h"} style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize: 16, width: 25, height: 25, float: 'right', marginRight: 20, }}></button> still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line can be overwritten something
`className={"fas fa-sliders-h"}` just remove the {}.
works here.

Verify if you’re receiving `handleClick` props correctly.

```react
class Header extends React.Component {
static displayName = Header.name;
    
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.sideMenuClick = this.sideMenuClick.bind(this);
}

sideMenuClick() {
    alert("hhhhhh");
    this.props.handleClick();
}

render() {
    return (
     <div className="headercon">
      <button 
          className="fas fa-sliders-h" 
          onClick={this.sideMenuClick} 
          style={{
          color: '#000000',
          fontSize: 16,
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          float: 'right',
          marginRight: 20,
        }} /> 
      </div>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed to this and now works also:

```
<button onClick={() => alert("cccc")} style={{ color: '#000000', fontSize: 16, width: 25, height: 25, float: 'right', marginRight: 20, }}><i className="fas fa-sliders-h"></i></button>
```